# ant custom rule to set debuggable on or off in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, ant

Update:  I have posted an answer/solution to this question below.

Here is what I have but regular expression is not quite right:

```
 <macrodef name="set-app-debuggable">
    <sequential>
        <echo>Setting  AndroidManifest.xml with debuggable set to true</echo>           
        <replaceregexp file="./AndroidManifest.xml" byline="true"
                match="name=&quot;debuggable&quot;&gt;(\w+)&lt;"
               replace="name=&quot;debuggable&quot;&gt;true&lt;"/>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Here is the AndroidManifest

```
 <application android:name="MyApplication" android:theme="@style/MyStyles.NoTitleBar"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true"    android:hardwareAccelerated="true" >
```

I am trying to set debuggable to false when this macro is called. Not sure how to specify element application and the ="false"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the macro

```
  <macrodef name="set-app-debuggable">
    <sequential>
        <echo>Updating AndroidManifest.xml with debuggable set to true</echo>           
       <replaceregexp file="./AndroidManifest.xml"
                            match='android:debuggable="(.*)"'
                            replace='android:debuggable="true"'
                            byline="false">         
        </replaceregexp>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```